# When booking a flight online is the checked luggage fee included in it?

Tags: air-travel, budget, airports, low-cost-carriers

Planning on booking a holiday abroad with expedia.com and was wondering is the fee for checked luggage so the suitcase that you check in covered with the holiday booking?

I was under the impression that you just hand them your suitcase or at the kiosk  and thats it and if it weighed more than the said limit you then have to pay extra.

Comment: It all depends on the airline and on the ticket. What applies for Ryanair is irrelevant to EasyJet, and what you can expect on EasyJet is unrelated to BA. This information should be trivial to find on each airline's website.

Comment: what do you mean by on the ticket? i assumed that as long as the suitcase meets or is under the limit it should be fine? when booking the holiday is that where you specify wether you will have a checked luggage and therefore gets included in the booking and paid?

Comment: Airlines often charge for luggage, specially on the shorter flights, like inside the USA or inside Europe, and holiday packs should include whether luggage is included. If it is not in the information, I would assume it is not. (Although for cross Atlantic flights, luggage is still included, as far as I know.)

Comment: "is the fee for hand luggage so the suitcase that you check in..." - not sure if I understand correctly, but you seem to mix things up: hand luggage aka carry-on luggage is the (smaller) suitcase you have with you in the cabin while larger bags are being checked in. Hand luggage is usually included in the price, while checked luggage often comes with an extra fee these days...

Comment: so does the checked luggage so all my clothes etc included in the price when i book the holiday? or it that only when at the airport they charge you. Never booked a holiday online nor by myself ever so not sure. I assumed that suitcases (checked baggage) as long as not over the weight limit is included in the booking like one per person typically and not weigh more than 23kg to 30 something kg cant remember

Comment: This is unclear. There are two types of luggage: hand luggage (the "carry-on" luggage you carry with you onto the plane) and checked luggage (the luggage you give them at the ticket counter and they take it away and put it under the plane). Different airlines have different policies. Hand luggage may be free (up to some limit) on one airline and cost money on another. Some airline may give one free 23kg checked bag on a transatlantic flight, while they charge for that on a flight within Europe. You'd need to check the airline's website or tell us specifically what situation applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Planning on booking a holiday abroad with expedia.com and was
>   wondering is the fee for checked luggage so the suitcase that you
>   check in covered with the holiday booking?

This will depend on your ticket and airline.

Specifically on Expedia, the fees for luggage and your luggage allowance are mentioned on the flight search page, as highlighted here:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**There is no rule. You must check the conditions of the fare.**

When it says you have a *baggage allowance* of so many pieces, that means that the price includes the cost of checking that many pieces of luggage as long as they satisfy the airline requirement for checked-luggage. You will still pay a fee if there are more pieces or they exceed allowed weight or dimensions. In some cases you can pay extra while some airlines do not accept anything beyond what it specified. It even changes depending on the date so the *only rule* is to read the airline site regarding luggage allowance.

When there is no baggage allowance, you will have the option of paying for checking in luggage. The majority of airlines allow you to take a carry-on and a personal item on board which have some size restrictions and *may* have weight limit. Some airlines do charge for the carry-on, so you must check the rules associated with the fare you are purchasing.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the way it works, there are no general rules and you cannot assume much. It's certainly not a given that a medium to large suitcase is always allowed free of charge (whether as cabin luggage or checked in to the hold). There are also many things you just cannot take with you as a regular passenger and thresholds you cannot exceed even if you are ready to pay a fee.

The 23 kg limit is something else, it's a recommended threshold for health and safety reasons as handling heavier weights all day long is dangerous. But some airlines will have a lower limit or won't allow any hold luggage without an extra charge. Others will let you take more than 23 kg of luggage as a matter of course provided it's spread among several bags and many will have different rules for different routes (and/or fares). Many also have a higher “hard” threshold and allow luggage up to 30 kg (e.g. for business class passengers or for an extra fee).

When considering a flight or holiday, you therefore have to look for information regarding the specific rules that apply to that specific airline, fare, or package.